# Почему нет деепричастия "бежа"?

Tags: деепричастия

Вроде бы нет никаких для этого препятствий. Или я ошибаюсь, и такое деепричастие есть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Препятствий действительно нет. Видимо, форма *бежа*  просто стала неблагозвучна и постепенно вышла из употребления.

В XVIII веке наблюдается более последовательная реализация возможности образования деепричастных форм, чем это имеет место в современном русском литературном языке. Речь идет об образованиях типа пиша, бежа, сладя (‘сладкий’), лия, бия, вияся, поя (от петь), бдя, мня, прясь и др.: *…как основательно Сенека, пиша об утешении к Албину, примечает (Тредиаковский, III-371); Добродетельный Писец, / Стих поя безвинно, / Сердца не вредит, сладя словом чувства чинно…* (там же, I-77). Подобные деепричастия были возможны на протяжении всего столетия, однако их образование от глаголов с чередованиями в основе, по-видимому, вызывало известные затруднения, попытки преодолеть которые выражались в использовании синонимичных форм с иными суффиксами: писать – пиша – пишучи – писав, бить – бия – биючи - бив, петь – поя – пев(ши), искать – ища – ищущи – искав и под.

[Пример](https://dslov.ru/pos/p2486.htm) использования формы бежа:

*Нет стыда избегать от беды и под мраками ночи*;

*Лучше бежа избежать от беды, чем вдаваться в погибель!*